# Integrate my web api with google drvie api and okta openid connect

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, okta

I have a .Net core web Api calling google drive api. The google drive api should authenticate the api call with [Okta](https://www.okta.com/) and authorize. How can this be achieved?

- Should i setup the auth application in [Okta](https://www.okta.com/) dashboard and generate client id and authentication token?
- Which before calling google api will be used to get bearer token from [Okta](https://www.okta.com/) and shared with the google api?
- Will be registered with google admin console and generate the tokens?

The domain of the api will be google.api.com ... so no where it is going to [Okta](https://www.okta.com/) for authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do with your Okta site will be after you have gained access to the google api on behalf of your users.   a bearer token from Okta will not grant you access to a google api you need to go though googles authorization server to get that.

In order to access the Google Drive api and access private user data.  The owner of that data will need to authorize your access.

To do this we use something called [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).  The issue you will have is begin that you say you are using a web api to call Google you will need to create a web application on the side where your users can authorize your application to access their data.   You will need to register your application with google on [Google Developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).  Create a web client credentials.  Then when the user has authorized your application to access their data you will will need to store the refresh token in your system associated with the user.

Then your web api will be able to access the users data by loading the refresh token and requesting a new access token.

There is currently only one sample [web-applications-asp.net-core-3](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3) for .net core web applications it doesn't show how to store the refresh token you will need to work that out.

I do have a video on setting up asp .net core with the google people api it might give you a starting point [How to get a Google users profile information, with C#.](https://youtu.be/aqjglbdFGPk) as well as one on how to create a [How to create Google Oauth2 web application credentials in 2021.](https://youtu.be/pBVAyU4pZOU)

Comment: Client told they have googke workspace. Into which they login using okta sso.

Comment: It doesn't matter, You still need to create a project on google developer console and create your tokens though googles Oath server.   The google drive api has nothing to do with workspace other than workspace contains a google drive access.   and Okta has nothing to do with googles authorization.

Comment: So, this document  https://support.google.com/a/topic/7579248 is not for when accessing api... I think what solution i am thinking of only works between applications. Not for accesing api. Thanks for the quick and detailed reply. I had tested the setup of google authorization via postman.

Comment: Remember signin is open id connect it is not Oauth2.  Your mixing authentication and authorization.